# how to install php5.5 in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I have few projects which are developed on php5.5.9. So I am trying to install php5.5.9 in ubuntu 17.10 but it is showing error.

I have used the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.5
```

It's showing the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package php5.5
E: Couldn't find any package by
glob 'php5.5' E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.5'
```

Could you please help me.

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.5 is no longer supported - http://php.net/supported-versions.php

You can install 5.6 using ppa:ondrej/php:
https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

Or you can compile from source, it's not so complicated:
https://secure.php.net/get/php-5.5.9.tar.gz/from/a/mirror

Answer (score 0):

You receive the error because php5 is outdated.

Execute : sudo apt-get install php7.0-imap

on the other way: use version:

try sudo apt-get install php5.5-rpm 
or
try sudo apt-get install php5.5-rpm

Answer (score 0):

You can get php5.5 tar file from old archive in [php official site](https://www.php.net).

To install from source I followed this [link](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215074947-How-to-install-a-custom-version-of-PHP). Its working good.